# How to switch tab position or replace tab position in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I'm using ViewPager and TabLayout to display a fragment which can be easily switched by selecting tabs.
 I have 5 tabs with Fragment one, two, three, four and five.

In fragment one I have a Button. How do I switch to other tabs, for example tab 4, by clicking that button instead of tabs.

Here is the Mainactivity

```
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new Home(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new speed(), "Quick Dial");
        adapter.addFragment(new hospital(), "Hospital");
        adapter.addFragment(new ambulance(), "Ambulance");
        adapter.addFragment(new funeral(), "Funeral");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    }
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

and fragment one contains

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                case 0:

                //Switch to tab position two
                case 1:

                //Switch to tab position three
                case 2:

               //Switch to tab position four

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a `BroadcastReciever` in your activity and send a brodcast from your first fragment to the activity as soon as the button is clicked.

Inside `BroadcastReciever` change the `ViewPager` index,

`viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);`

Additionally You can also send the index to be switched to, by passing data through intent.

Answer (score 2):

You can write in code in  onClick(View v)

viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);

Index is the fragment number which you want to show. 
Try this. I hope your problem will be solved.